# iOS/UI Automation: UIAActionSheet does not have possibilities to manipulate with buttons

Tags: ios, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

My question is related to UI Automation template from XCode's Instruments tool. How does UI Automation support UIActionSheet testing? I know that there is a UIAActionSheet element and I was able to obtain it in my application. But I do not know how to get and manipulate with buttons from the action sheet. UI Automation does not provide any elements for these buttons. The UI Automation documentation does not have any info on the matter either. See the link below. It looks like this control does not use UIButton class for the buttons and renders them in some specific way. Could you give me some clue how to reach the buttons from UIAActionSheet? Thank you.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAActionSheetClassReference/UIAActionSheet/UIAActionSheet.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009895

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see there is method to return default button for each action sheet, which is Cancel button. As there is no other 'default' buttons for action sheet you need to implement those on your own.
One thing to notice woorth apple reference is that it skips methods for given class which are inherited from parent. UIAActionSheet (like most UIA elements) inherits all methods from UIAElement class. Check [this reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/UIAElement/UIAElement.html). You should be able to get array of all buttons from actionsheet by calling

```
var arrButtons = objActionSheet.buttons();
```

Then you can check by name property which one you need (again method from UIAElement `name()` ).

Alliteratively, if you check which element in array you are interested in you could call  that button directly (assuming, that you won't change ActionSheet) by using UIAElement method `elements()`.
For example if you want to tap second button in ActionSheet tree, you just call

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().actionSheet().elements()[1].tap();
```

Maybe you can skip localTarget(), not sure, but code above should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes. I do understand the UI Automation idea. The problems is I have several buttons declared in my UIActionSheet instance. And I tried to obtain actionSheet.buttons() as well but it returns an empty array.

Comment: Setting isAccessibilityElement does not help either.

_myActionSheet.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
_myActionSheet.accessibilityLabel = @"myActionSheet"

Although the script shows the correct name for the actionSheet

actionSheet.name() == "myActionSheet"

Comment: Hmm... that is strange if array is empty. Is elements() method return also empty Array? Do you physically see buttons on AvtionSheet when it is called by application?

Comment: The elements() method also returns an empty array. I think this a specific implementation of UIActionSheet class. It does not use UIButton instances internally and draws buttons directly. I have tried to create my own UIActionSheetExt class to support UIAActionSheet but it is not available from the UIActionSheet.

Comment: And now you now :) Doing things Apple approved way, otherwise it is not supported :P
Consider using standard way of implementing controls, or use other approach to automation
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/12/sample-iphone-application-with-complete.html

Answer (score 6):

I have found a solution for the problem using direct tapping simulation. It is not an excellent solution but at least it works. I have asked the same question in the Apple Developer Forum but did not get any response.

So, the function below is my solution. I have tested it and it performs well. I will still continue to search for better approach.

```
function tapActionSheetButton(target, actionSheet, buttonIndex)
{
    var headerHeight = 28;
    var buttonHeight = 50;

    if (buttonIndex >= 0) 
    {
        var actionSheetRect = actionSheet.rect();
        UIALogger.logMessage("actionSheet:{rect:{origin:{x:" + actionSheetRect.origin.x.toString() 
                             + ", y:" + actionSheetRect.origin.y.toString()
                             + "}, size:{width:" + actionSheetRect.size.width.toString()
                             + ", height:" + actionSheetRect.size.height.toString()
                             + "}}}");
        var xOffset = actionSheetRect.size.width / 2;
        var yOffset = headerHeight + buttonIndex * buttonHeight + buttonHeight / 2;
        if (yOffset < actionSheetRect.size.height) {
            var tap_x = actionSheetRect.origin.x + xOffset;
            var tap_y = actionSheetRect.origin.y + yOffset;
            target.tap({x:tap_x, y:tap_y});
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var message = "Cannot tap button " + buttonIndex.toString() + ". It does not exist";
        throw message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since my action sheet was in a popover this returns a nil element:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().actionSheet();
```

This does return the action sheet:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().popover().actionSheet();
```

But it has nil elements() and buttons().

So I used MikhailV's function to tap the buttons.

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var actionSheet = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().popover().actionSheet();
var buttonIndex = 1;

tapActionSheetButton(target, actionSheet, buttonIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to keep it organized like me:

```
function getTarget() {
    return UIATarget.localTarget();
}

function getApp() {
    return getTarget().frontMostApp();
}

function getWindow() {
    return getApp().mainWindow();
}

function tapActionSheetButtonInIndex(index) {
    var actionSheet = getApp().actionSheet() || getWindow().popover().actionSheet();
    actionSheet.buttons()[index].tap(); 
}
```