# Cannot perform action on invalid element: UIAElementNil

Tags: javascript, ios-ui-automation

Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error:

```
Cannot perform action on invalid element: UIAElementNil from target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().popover().actionSheet().buttons()["Save Note"]
```

Code:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();
target.logElementTree();
UIALogger.logPass("Stick Note Save Start"); 
app.navigationBar().toolbar().buttons()["Plus"].tap(); 
app.keyboard().typeString("Ki");
window.popover().actionSheet().buttons()["Save Note"].tap();
UIALogger.logPass("StickNoteSaveEnd");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check correct hierarchy. 
Then, try to use 
"app.popover().actionSheet().buttons()["Save Note"].tap();"
If it does not work for you, please give some details regarding elements structure/buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in action sheet access from javascript.  You can see my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15287666/18159).

Bascially I think actionSheet() always returns nil to buttons and elements.  It's not supposed to, but everything I've seen suggests otherwise.

MikhailV worked out a function to tap the correct button [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5331896/18159).