# How to access actionSheet (and it's buttons) in UIAutomation with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiactionsheet, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I'm having a very simple app, which includes a TableViewController, which displays a table with few custom cells with image, label and a button, and when you hit a button, actionSheet shows up. And so, in my custom java script (using Instruments-UIAutomation) I want to push button in my table (and I can do that without any problems), and then when actionSheet appears I just want to tap the only button (Cancel button) that it shows.

And I don't know how to do it properly. So here's my js code:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var main = app.mainWindow();

main.tableViews()[0].cells()[1].buttons()["DetailsButton"].tap();
target.delay(5);
main.actionSheet().elements()[0].tap();
```

And that's the message I'm getting:

```
Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'main.actionSheet()') on line 9 of New%20Script
```

I've also tried `actionSheet().buttons()[0].tap();` - didn't help, keep getting same error.

I even tried to access actionSheet by it's accessibleLabel:

```
main.actionSheet()["CellNumberSheet"].elements()[0].tap();
```

If it would help, that's the way I'm showing my actionSheet:

```
[actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
```

The elements hierarchy also seems to be correct.

[image]

Didn't find much of a helpful info on it in web... so any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 6):

On iOS8, the action sheet buttons and elements just didn't seem to work so I checked in SparkInspector and it uses a collection view now:

This code will tap the bottom button that isn't the cancel button:

`target.frontMostApp().actionSheet().collectionViews()[0].visibleCells()[0].tap()`

Comment: This is true for iPhones, but on iPad I had to access the actionSheet before: window.popover().elements()[0].collectionViews()[0].visibleCells()["Enroll new appliance"].tap();

Answer (score 2):

When you want to tap on actionSheet you must use as below:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();

target.frontMostApp().actionSheet().buttons()["Cancel"].tap();
```

But if you use `window.actionSheet()` it will return error.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to use app.actionSheet() to get the actionsheet.

See [UIAApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAApplicationClassReference/Introduction/Introduction.html)

```
app.actionSheet().elements()[0].tap();
```

This should work

Comment: This takes me a little further, though still doesn't work... now when I try to tap the button of actionSheet in the way you suggested, the other error appears: `Cannot perform action on invalid element: UIAElementNil from target.frontMostApp().actionSheet().elements()[0]`... Also all methods like `checkIsValid()`, `isEnabled()`, `isVisible()` return False when I apply them to my actionSheet(), and `actionSheet().name()` returns an empty string (while when on a screenshot in my post you can see it has a valid name "CellNumberSheet")...

Comment: That's interesting, how about using app.windows()[2].elements()[1] to access the actionsheet?

Comment: The last way you suggested to access the actionSheet works fine, and all methods like isVisible, checkIsValid and isEnabled are returning True. Though still cannot tap on actionSheet's buttons! Trying `app.windows()[2].elements()[1].elements()[0].tap()` and `app.windows()[2].elements()[1].buttons()[0].tap()`. No success,  it throws an error "Cannot perform action on invalid element". Temporarily using solution to tap asctionSheet buttons as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5331896/3065769

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
 //check that action sheet is on the screen
   app.actionSheetIsValid();

 //add some delay
   target.delay(2);

 //check that the button is on the actionSheet
   actionSheet.actionSheetButton("Cancel");

 //add some delay
   target.delay(2);

 //touch Exit button
   actionSheet.tapActionSheetButtonByName("Cancel");
```